# How can I inject props into a Provider component?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have an entry point file that exports a Provider wrapping a component. For the life of me I can't get props into it. Any ideas?

entry point file that I call sometime in my app. It is a seperate file, and lives outside my app. Thus, the wrapping of a Provider.

```
const App2 = 
    <Provider store={myOtherStore}>
        <Application />
    </Provider>
;

export default App2;
```

I tried this and some other ways.. but no luck. The entry component and any other component tied to Application does not see any new props other than "actions and state"

```
const App2 = (props) =>
    return (
    <Provider store={myOtherStore}>
        <Application data={props} />
    </Provider>
    )
;

export default App2;
```

basically, in my working file I'd call that above like so:

```
    const newApp = React.cloneElement(newApplication, {
        productID
    });
```

Edit: In the Application component (the one the Provider surrounds), I am using connect on that and bringing in the actions/state. It is just in this component "Application" I do not have access to the props I am trying to pass in. I just see {actions:{}, state: {}}

Comment: It works just fine.

Comment: how are you trying to get the props? are you using connect? are you defining context type and trying to access the store directly?

Comment: @zerkms - how is it fine? I can't get at those props. I updated with some more info

Comment: @jamesemanon well, I just tried it and I can get those props. `<Provider store={store}>
        <App foo="bar" />
    </Provider>` --- for this code I definitely can see the `this.props.foo`. So it's a problem with your code somewhere - just chop the extra things from your code to localise the actual issue.

Comment: Hey @zerkms Thanks. Your confirmation made me relook at my code and yes, it was a simple mistake and now it is fixed. Thanks a bunch!